# I'm having trouble getting this addition subroutine to work

Tags: assembly, subroutine, addition, 68000

I am writing an addition program for my assembly language class in Easy68k but I keep having the same issue. Whenever I run the program it allows me to input up to 10 numbers (the allotted size of my array) and then it outputs the message saying it's calculating but then I just get an endless printout of y's with umlauts. Any issues you can see right off the bat with my program that would be causing it to do this?

I've searched for syntax on subroutines because I'm positive that is what I am doing wrong, but I cannot find anything.

```
ORG $2000
ARRAY   DS.W    10
ZDONE       DC.W    'Enter values. Zero when done.'
FULL        DC.W    'That is all the input allowed. Calculating sum now...'
OERROR      DC.W    'The values you entered caused an overflow condition.'
REPEAT      DC.W    'Do you want to repeat? [0=No, 1=Yes].'

START       ORG     $2800

MAIN    LEA         ZDONE,A1
        MOVE.B      #14,D0          ;
        TRAP        #15
        LEA         ARRAY,A0

        MOVE.B      #0,D3
INPUT   MOVE.B      #4,D0
        TRAP        #15
        MOVE.W      D1,(A0)+
        BEQ         SUB
        ADD.B       #1,D3
        CMPA        #$2012,A0
        BNE         INPUT
        LEA         FULL,A1
        MOVE.B      #14,D0           ; Outputs the FULL string
        TRAP        #15

SUB     SUB.W       A0,A0
        BSR         SUM              ; Begins to calculate sum

        CMP         #1,D0
        BNE         NoV
        LEA         OERROR,A1
        MOVE.B      #14,D0
        TRAP        #15
        BRA         AGAIN

NoV     LEA         $D1,A1
        MOVE.B      #14,D0
        TRAP        #15

AGAIN   LEA         REPEAT,A1
        MOVE.B      #14,D0
        TRAP        #15
        MOVE.B      #4,D0
        TRAP        #15
        MOVE.B      #1,D0
        CMP.B       D0,D1
        BEQ         START
        STOP        #$3800

        ORG         $3800        
SUM     LEA         ARRAY,A0
        ADD.W       #$A0,D1
        BVC         NoV
        SUB.B       #1,D3
        BNE         SUM
        MOVE.B      #1,D0
        BRA         RETURN
        CLR.B       D0
RETURN  RTS
        END         START
```

Answer (score 2):

The flood of ÿ comes from here:

```
NoV     LEA         $D1,A1
        MOVE.B      #14,D0
        TRAP        #15
```

You're loading an *immediate value* of 0xD1 into A1. That's what the $ is for: it means immediate addressing. Debuggers are useful here: if you run the program up to the MOVE.B line, you'll see that A1 has a value of 0x000000D1. This is the address of the string to print using TRAP, right? What's in memory at 0x000000D1? It's undefined; in this case, the emulator is initializing memory to 0xFF, which corresponds to the ÿ character.

This might be wrong:

```
SUB     SUB.W       A0,A0
```

You're subtracting A0 from A0, effectively setting A0 to 0.

I suspect this is wrong too:

```
SUM     LEA         ARRAY,A0
        ADD.W       #$A0,D1
```

The ADD is adding an *immediate value* of 0xA0 to register D1. You probably want a direct add instead:

```
        ADD.W       A0,D1
```

---

A couple more things:

You're loading ARRAY into A0 at the start of each loop in SUM. You should probably do it before the loop:

```
SUB     LEA         ARRAY,A0
        BSR         SUM
```

Inside of SUM, ignore what I said and use indirect addressing. This will take the actual value from the array and add it to the accumulator (I presume this is D1):

```
SUM     ADD.W       (A0)+,D1
```

NoV looks like it's displaying the current value of the accumulator, right? You're using a conditional branch to it: okay, you probably only want it to display once you've finished summing. But BVC isn't actually a sub branch! It won't save the return pointer. Instead, I would move it to the part of SUM that executes after the counter reaches 0, and I would use BSR:

```
SUM     ADD.W       (A0)+,D1
        SUB.B       #1,D3
        BNE         SUM
        BSR         NoV
        MOVE.B      #1,D0
        BRA         RETURN
        CLR.B       D0
RETURN  RTS
```

Note that you'll still get the overflow thing. I don't understand what you're doing there so I'll let you figure it out. Also note that since you're using an unconditional branch to RETURN, the CLR will never get executed and so it's impossible for SUM to return 0.

After this change, it's important to modify NoV to act like a subroutine by returning with RTS. Note that there's a TRAP value for displaying the integer value of D1 as a string, which is probably what you want:

```
NoV     MOVE.B      #3,D0
        TRAP        #15
        RTS
```

At this point I can get it to add numbers and display the result, but it always shows the overflow thing. Fix your subroutines, then re-evaluate the logic flow of your program.